# Prevent outer double quotes in my list

Tags: python, python-2.7

My program (not shown) is breaking because of the outer double quotes that are getting inserted into my list.  How can I make it so that my list x does not have double quotes in it?

```
s = "('x',),('y',)"
print s
('x',),('y',)

x = []
x.append(s)
print x
["('x',),('y',)"]
```

When I print x, I want it the output to look like this (without the double quotes)
    print x
    [('x',),('y',)]

Comment: `s` isn't a list, it's a string.

Comment: Right, the contents of s are coming from a huge file.  I am hoping to take the contents of the file and append it all at once into an empty list.

Comment: So you want to convert a string into a list?

Comment: The quotes are there because x is a one-item list. Whose sole member is a string.

Comment: The `print` of a container **always** shows the `repr` of each item.  You can change that only by defining your own container class that does weird things in `__str__` (you shouldn't, but that's another issue).  Better, and cleaner: define a **function** `munge` that takes your container and returns whatever weird string you want, then `print munge(x)`.

Comment: What are you really trying to do? To get the output you want you could just `print '[%s]' % s`, but I suspect that's not what you want because you are trying to do something else and get us to debug your invalid solution, instead of presenting the problem so we can come up with better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to convert a string representation of Python data to the actual data structure:

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> s = "('x',),('y',)"
>>> literal_eval(s)
(('x',), ('y',))
```

literal_eval works similarly to `eval` but can only produce literal Python data from strings: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None. Quite a bit safer than `eval` alone.

If you actually want a list vs a tuple from your string:

```
>>> list(literal_eval(s))
[('x',), ('y',)]
```

Comment: Oh, that's nice. Not sure what I was doing the day they announced that library. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid importing libraries, here's another method:

```
[(k,) for k in tuple(s) if k.isalnum()]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
>>> s = "('x',),('y',)"
>>> s = eval(s)
>>> x = []
>>> x.extend(s)
>>> print(x)
[('x',),('y',)]
```

But do check that you are doing everything correctly, and this is really what you want. It definitely doesn't seem like the most intuitive (or pythonic) way of approaching any problem.

Comment: Or just... x = eval(s)

Comment: possibly `x=list(eval(s))`. Still don't know what the point of this is.

Comment: `eval()` is pretty much always a bad idea. There are very few valid cases to use it.

Comment: Don't know if I would agree, it's definitely deep down on the list of things I would reach for, but do you see a better way of achieving what OP wants? (without further information what it is that he *really* wants)